# JDBC Template and AngularJS with RESTful web application

Tags: java, angularjs, jdbc, spring-boot, restful-architecture

I am trying to populate an HTML table with data from an MS SQL Database. I have set my app.properties for the sql server and declared my jdbcTemplate in my .java file. I am entirely new to AngularJS and jdbcTemplate. Can someone please offer some example code or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!!

**table.html**

```
<h2>Industry Maintenance SIC Table</h2>

<div ng-controller="tableController">

    <p>Click <a ng-click="loadObjects()">here</a> to load data.</p>

    <!-- table -->
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr style="font-weight: bold">
            <td style="width:40%">SIC Code</td>
            <td style="width:50%">SIC Code Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="object in objects">
            <td>{{object.code}}</td>
            <td>{{object.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

**table.controller.js**

```
(function () {
      'use strict';

      angular.module('support-dash.pi.table').controller('tableController', tableController);

      function tableController($scope, $http){

          $scope.objects = [];

          $scope.loadObjects = function(){

              ***DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
          }


      };
})();
```

**HelloResource.java**

```
    package supportdash.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    public String retrieve() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

}
```

Comment: As for what you put there... You make a JDBC connection, and you populate the array with your data. Which, it's hard to really provide an accurate answer without knowing what you database schema looks like.

Comment: @cricket_007 I added my .java but I haven't really done anything there other than declare the template

Comment: I see now. So, step 1 -- You need to actually write a SQL query to get some data in the Java code.

Comment: And step 2 would be preferably formatting a JSON string output from those SQL results. Step 3 is making sure your web server works correctly when you hit `/hello`... And **then** you start building the Angular app using AJAX requests.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets strat from Sprin. You want a RESTful api so there is how a example controller should look like :

```
@Controller
   @RequestMapping("/hello")
   public class ShowController {

   @Autowired
   private YourRepository yr;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/getObjects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public List<Object> home(Model model) {
       List<Object> objects = yr.getObjects();
       return objects;
       }

}
```

Now it is better if you use services and in your controller @Autowired a service like *YourService* in which you call the repository and do every kind of logic over your data from the data base. But lets keep it as simple as we can.

Now `YourRepository` should look like this :

```
public interface YourRepository{
  public List<Object> getObjects();
}
```

and of course the implementation of our interface :

```
@Repository
public class YourRepositoryJdbc implements YourRepository{

   @Autowired
   private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTmpl;

   public List<Object> getObjects(){

      StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
      sql.append("SELECT ob.id, ob.name ");
      sql.append("FROM objects ob ");
      sql.append("WHERE ob.del_flag = 0 ");

      List<Object> allObjects = jdbcTmpl.query(sql.toString(), new ResultSetExtractor<List<Object>>(){ 
         @Override
         public List<Object> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

            while(rs.next()) {
               Object local = new Object();
               local.setId(rs.getIng("id"));
               local.setName(rs.getString("name"));
               allObjects.add(local);
            }
            return allObjects;

         }
    }
}
```

Now this will work if you have a table named *OBJECTS* in your SQL. Also when you go to your browser and you write http://localhost:8080/hello/getObjects you should get a JSON object with your *Objects*.

Now from the client you can use Ajax requests to call the REST service :

```
    var getAllObjects = function() {
        var request = $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/hello/getObjects',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {

            }
        });
        return request.then(function (data) {
            return data;
        }, function (error) {
            return error;
        });
    }
    $scope.loadObjects = getAllObjects();
```

It should look something like this.